# 「microsoft-edge:」 を「https://」に付けるとハイパーリンクにならない

Tags: mail, url

### 達成したいこと

「sendGrid」 を使って（html形式）、「gmail」, 「hotmail」 へ "microsoft-edge:https://..." 形式のハイパーリンクを本文に含めたメールを送信したい.

### 実際に試したこと・確認できたこと

`<a href="microsoft-edge:https://....">テスト</a>`形式でメールを送信したが、ハイパーリンクにならずただの文字列として本文に記載される.
※`<a href="https://....">テスト</a>`形式で送信するとハイパーリンクになる.

### 教えて欲しいこと

「"microsoft-edge:https://..." 形式のハイパーリンクを本文に含めたメールを送信する上で、
クロスサイトスクリプティング（XSS）対策のようなセキュリティ問題で仕様上送信できない！」のような情報があれば教えてください！

Comment: `microsoft-edge:https://...` の記述が仮にリンクとして認識されたとして、どのように動作することを期待していますか？単に `https://...` と書いた時との違いは何でしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL を構成する文字列のうち、`://` より前にある先頭の部分はプロトコルと呼ばれます。

**例:**

```sh
https://www.example.com   # "https" がプロトコル
```

"メールの本文に含めたハイパーリンク" ということは、その文字列を解釈するのはメーラーになるはずですが、プロトコルというのはある程度種類が決まっています。(http, https, ftp ...)

`microsoft-edge:https://` という記述は恐らく Edge 独自の仕様によるものだと思うので、その他大勢のブラウザやメーラーではこの文字列を URL と認識しないのは正しい動作です。

実現しようとしている事は、恐らく Windows のデスクトップショートカットでのみ使用できる機能ではないでしょうか？

[EdgeでURLを含むショートカットを作成する方法](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/edge/forum/edge_other-edge_win10/edge%E3%81%A7url%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%80/0b76cde8-ec19-4e66-be8a-522d3cf24385)

> MicroSoft Edge　に関してですが、URLを含んだデスクトップショートカットを作成したいです。
> ショートカットの作成で `microsoft-edge:https://www.google.co.jp` を指定すると
> Edgeで起動するショートカットは作成できましたが …
>
> (後略)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます.
実現しようとしている事は、

「ユーザーにリンク付きメールを送信 -> 受け取ったユーザーがリンクをクリック -> edge以外のブラウザを使用しているユーザーにedgeで任意のページを開くようにする」

です。
@cubick さんがおっしゃるように、「その他大勢のブラウザやメーラーではこの文字列を URL と認識しない」ので

Comment: あれば、上記仕様の実現は不可能そうですね。
ありがとうございますm(_ _)m